# Errors in Installing Angular on Mac

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I was trying to install angular on my macbook
but some errors appeared that I couldn't understand

here is a copy of what I wrote in my terminal

```
S-MacBook-Pro-491:~ s$ node -v
v8.9.4
S-MacBook-Pro-491:~ s$ npm -v
5.6.0
S-MacBook-Pro-491:~ s$ npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/s/.npm/_logs/2018-03-04T23_55_05_519Z-debug.log
S-MacBook-Pro-491:~ s$
```

Comment: As you're using "-g" (--global) option for installing angular cli, you should run `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`

Comment: In MacOS / Linux, you need a "root" privilege to install node packages globally, typically use `sudo` command to run "npm", **copy `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`** to your terminal and run it, and then it'll prompt for password, type your current password then you'll get it done.

Answer (score 0):

To install NPM modules globally you may need to run the same command with `sudo` or you'll need to change the permissions of `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`.

If you're using a system like Homebrew, you may have inadvertently run an NPM installation command with `sudo` before which has set the permissions of those directories as `root`. You can repair this with:

```
sudo chown -R me:staff /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Where `me` is your username and `staff` is the default group on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of access errors  we can take help of Homebrew, these steps can help:

1. Homebrew [installation](https://brew.sh/): (on terminal)

   ```
   /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   ```
2. `brew install node`

   Check version: `node -v`, `npm -v`
3. `brew install -g angular-cli`

   Check version: `ng --version`
4. `ng new First-App`